# Are seeks cheaper than reads, and does forward-seeking fall foul of the sequential-access optimization?

Tags: file, winapi, io

Consider [`SetFilePointer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365541(v=vs.85).aspx). The documentation on MSDN (nor `learn.microsoft.com`) does not explain if a forward seek constitutes sequential access or not - this has implications for applications' IO performance.

For example, if you use `CreateFile` with `FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS` then Win32 will use a different buffering and caching strategy compared to `FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN` - if you're reading a file from start to finish then you can expect better performance than with the random-access option.

However, supposing the file format you're reading does not necessitate that every byte (or even buffer-page) be read into memory, such as a flag in the file's header indicates that the first 100 bytes - or 100 kilobytes - contains no useful data. Is it wise to call `ReadFile` to read the next 100 bytes (or 100 kilobytes - or more?) - or will it always be faster to call `SetFilePointer( file, 100, NULL, FILE_CURRENT )` to skip-over those 100 bytes?

If it is generally faster to use `SetFilePointer`, does the random-access vs sequential option make a difference? I would think that seeking forward constitutes a form of random-access because you could seek forward beyond the currently cached buffer (and any future buffers that the OS might have pre-loaded for you behind the scenes) but in that case will Windows always discard the cached buffers and re-read from disk? Is there a way to find out the maximum amount one can seek-forward without triggering a buffer reload?

(I would try to profile and benchmark to test my hypothesis, but all my computers at-hand have NVMe SSDs - obviously things will be very different on platter drives).

Comment: `SetFilePointer` is only set `CurrentByteOffset` in [`FILE_OBJECT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545834(v=vs.85).aspx) by I/O manager. even file system not called. so this call absolute independent from file open mode, disk, etc. + this is absolute senseless call - we always can pass direct offset in read or write operation

Comment: You are setting the wrong premise: Neither `FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS` nor `FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN` make any promises. Both are documented as *"The system can use this as a hint to optimize file caching."* They may not do anything, or the optimized caching strategy may not be available on some systems. You have to be prepared for the flags to do nothing, irrespective of whether `SetFilePointer` constitutes sequential access.

Comment: *or the optimized caching strategy may not be available on some systems* - this is software part of windows, available on every windows version. `FILE_SEQUENTIAL_ONLY` and `FILE_RANDOM_ACCESS` options from create file - converted to `FO_SEQUENTIAL_ONLY` and `FO_RANDOM_ACCESS` flags in file object . how it used for read ahead strategy - can look [here](https://github.com/Zer0Mem0ry/ntoskrnl/tree/master/Cache) (of course concrete implementation changed from version to version). and all this have nothing common with `SetFilePointer`.

Comment: @RbMm: Yes, the cache manager is software. And it can be disabled. At any rate, I'm not making this up. It's straight from the documentation.

Comment: @IInspectable - *And it can be disabled* read ahead can be disable on system wide level but not per file ? (i not speak about delay write). anyway - answer on question not depend from cache manager at all. any read another file range before need range read will be only slower than direct needed range read

Comment: @RbMm: I wouldn't be surprised if the cache manager *can* be disabled altogether. If not today, then maybe tomorrow, because some company asked Microsoft to implement a Group Policy to do so. It can be disabled per file, though. Anyway, since you don't understand, what contracts are, I won't be able to explain any more of this to *you*.

Answer (score 1):

at first about `SetFilePointer`.

`SetFilePointer` internally called [`ZwSetInformationFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567096(v=vs.85).aspx) with [`FilePositionInformation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545848(v=vs.85).aspx). it full [*handled*](https://github.com/Zer0Mem0ry/ntoskrnl/blob/master/Io/iomgr/qsinfo.c#L1049) by I/O manager - the file system is not even called. all what is done on this call : `CurrentByteOffset` from [`FILE_OBJECT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545834(v=vs.85).aspx) is [*set*](https://github.com/Zer0Mem0ry/ntoskrnl/blob/master/Io/iomgr/qsinfo.c#L1091) to given position.

so this call absolute independent from file buffering and caching strategy. more - this is absolute senseless call, which only waste time - we always can set direct offset in call to `ReadFile` or `WriteFile` - look in [`OVERLAPPED`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684342(v=vs.85).aspx) `Offset` and `OffsetHigh`. `SetEndOfFile` ? but much more better and effective call [`ZwSetInformationFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567096(v=vs.85).aspx) with [`FileEndOfFileInformation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545780(v=vs.85).aspx) or [`SetFileInformationByHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365539(v=vs.85).aspx) with [`FileEndOfFileInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364224(v=vs.85).aspx) (`SetEndOfFile` of course internally call `ZwSetInformationFile` with `FileEndOfFileInformation` and before it call `ZwQueryInformationFile` with `FilePositionInformation` for read `CurrentByteOffset` from `FILE_OBJECT` - so you simply do 2-3 unnecessary extra calls to kernel in case `SetEndOfFile`). not exist situation when call to `SetFilePointer` really need.

so file position - is only software variable (`CurrentByteOffset` in `FILE_OBJECT`) which used primary by I/O manager - 
filesystem always get read/write request with explicit offset - in `FastIoRead` as *in* argument or in `IO_STACK_LOCATION.Parameters.Read.ByteOffset`
the I/O manager get this offset or from explicit *ByteOffset* value to `NtReadFile` or from `CurrentByteOffset` in `FILE_OBJECT` if *ByteOffset* not present (*NULL* pointer for *ByteOffset*)
`ReadFile` use *NULL* pointer for *ByteOffset* if *NULL* pointer for `OVERLAPPED`, otherwise use pointer to `OVERLAPPED.Offset`

about question - are exist sense sequential read all bytes or just read from needed offset ?

in case we open file without caching ( `FILE_NO_INTERMEDIATE_BUFFERING`) - we have no choice *Offset* and *Length* passed to `ReadFile` or `WriteFile` must be a multiple of the sector size

in case using cache - we anyway nothing gain if read some additional (and not needed to us bytes) before read actual needed bytes. in any case file system will be need read this bytes from disk, if it yet not read - reading another bytes does not accelerate this process.

with `FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN` cache manager read more sectors from disk than need for complete current request and next reading at sequential offset - will (as minimum partially) fall cache - so count of direct read from disk (most expensive operation) will be less. but when you need read file at specific offset - sequential read bytes before this offset not help in any way - anyway will be need read this bytes

in other words - you anyway need read required bytes (at specific offset) from file - and if you before this read some another bytes - this not increase performance. only diminishes

so if you need read file at some offset - just read at this offset. and not use `SetFilePointer`. use explicit offset on `OVERLAPPED`

Comment: *"Effective"* and *"efficient"* aren't the same thing. `ZwSetInformationFile` is certainly no more effective than any other call that performs the same operation.

Comment: @IInspectable - `ZwSetInformationFile` (with `FilePositionInformation`) at all not need

Comment: That's not the point. The point is, that you keep using *"effective"* whenever you mean (presumably) *"efficient"*, which generally invalidates an otherwise true statement.

Comment: @IInspectable - i try explain (in begin) that use `SetFilePointer` have no sense at all. never. this is both not "Effective" and not "efficient"

Comment: Calling `SetFilePointer` followed by a `ReadFile` is **equally** effective as passing the file offsets through an `OVERLAPPED` structure. Now before you get all worked up about how *"senseless"* all of this is, do make sure to visit an online translation service, and type in the words *"effective"* and *"efficient"*.

Comment: @IInspectable - *is equally effective* - **no**. this is absolute false. separate *SetFilePointer* - this call to kernel with may be ~100*N instructions. when we use direct file offset in `OVERLAPPED` - we skip this phase. you want say that extra call to kernel - not a problem and not have any difference ?

Comment: Please get yourself a dictionary, and look up the terms *"effective"* and *"efficient"*. Unless you absolutely, positively want to make an idiot out of yourself, don't write back until you understand the difference.

Comment: @IInspectable - you say - *Calling SetFilePointer followed by a ReadFile is equally effective as passing the file offsets through an OVERLAPPED structure* - this if false. difference in performance is **huge**. of course on single call -it will be not visible (from human view). however if permanent programming this way - will be even visible effect

Comment: *"Effectiveness"* has ***nothing*** to do with performance. Two operations that have the same **effect** are said to be equally effective. Why did you not get yourself a dictionary, check an online service, ask friends, or otherwise try to learn?

Comment: @IInspectable - you already play with words. *Two operations that have the same effect are said to be equally effective.* - but performance for example can be very different.

Comment: Performance is not an effect. Performance is effect per time. This isn't playing with words. Had you looked up those words in a dictionary, you'd know by now.